# How to add "data" to an array?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below metadata in an variable, but how can I add it to an array? I would like add the "data" to an array.

```
    {'count': 130447,
    'data': [{'amount': '5',
       'date': 1653943413806,
       'direction': 'BUY',
       'id': 314901,
       'matched_order_id': 108327933,
       'order_id': 108336049,
       'price': '0.1326',
       'symbol': 'ECS/EUR',
       'trading_pair_id': 48},
      {'amount': '40',
       'date': 1653943403928,
       'direction': 'BUY',
       'id': 314900,
       'matched_order_id': 108327933,
       'order_id': 108336031,
       'price': '0.1326',
       'symbol': 'ECS/EUR',
       'trading_pair_id': 48}],
    'limit': 2,
    'offset': 0}
```

Comment: There are no arrays in Python. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I really get you question, please make it clearer, but from what I understood, do you want this ?

```
import numpy as np

dictionary = {'count': 130447,
        'data': [{'amount': '5',
        'date': 1653943413806,
        'direction': 'BUY',
        'id': 314901,
        'matched_order_id': 108327933,
        'order_id': 108336049,
        'price': '0.1326',
        'symbol': 'ECS/EUR',
        'trading_pair_id': 48},
        {'amount': '40',
        'date': 1653943403928,
        'direction': 'BUY',
        'id': 314900,
        'matched_order_id': 108327933,
        'order_id': 108336031,
        'price': '0.1326',
        'symbol': 'ECS/EUR',
        'trading_pair_id': 48}],
        'limit': 2,
        'offset': 0}

arr = np.array(dictionary['data'])

print(arr)
```

output:

```
[{'amount': '5', 'date': 1653943413806, 'direction': 'BUY', 'id': 314901, 'matched_order_id': 108327933, 'order_id': 108336049, 'price': '0.1326', 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'trading_pair_id': 48}
 {'amount': '40', 'date': 1653943403928, 'direction': 'BUY', 'id': 314900, 'matched_order_id': 108327933, 'order_id': 108336031, 'price': '0.1326', 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'trading_pair_id': 48}]
```

Comment: As a rule, one should not attempt to answer a question that is unclear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, but I'm not sure I approach this correct. My goal is collect data every 30 sec and then send this to telegram. I want monitoring the price for some crypto. So now the output is like that how do go throug each of them and do something with it?

Comment: I should just for the record mention that I'm not so good to python, but I'm learning.

Comment: I get this error:

    arr = np.array(response_raw['data'])
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Valnurat can you show me your code ? or at least what's inside the response_raw variable ?

Comment: I found out how to get the output as yours, but how do I get the value for 'date'?

Comment: iterate over your data, each element is a dictionnary itself. `dates = [el['date'] for el in arr]`

Comment: Ok. I the output I see 2 lines. I want to go through line by line and do something with each element -  how can I accomplish that? Because `dates = [el['date'] for el in arr]` give me for all.

Comment: dates goes through each element and extracts its date, isn't that what you want ?

Comment: I want to go through line by line and do something with each element - how can I accomplish that?
Sorry for being lame.

Comment: you can just loop over it, your array `arr` is an iterable, use a `for` loop.

Comment: Just a small follow up question. How do I copy the key 'data' to another dictionary for comparing?